# Is it fardh on me to wear a niqab?

Tags: practical-islam

I was 14 when my father and mother forced me to wear a niqab without even describing me the benefits of this. Obviously, I knew but I never had that sense of acknowledgement in my head. On their force and beating, I started wearing niqab just to avoid any conflict in the house. It's been more than 7 years, I've been wearing it but I never loved this act with my full heart. I always wanted to take it off. Now, I'm 22 and in a medical field. I wore abaya and niqab whenever my parents are around and took them off in medical school. I dress modestly and also in favour of complete hijab. But whenever I wear niqab it's like I'm being hypocrite or dual faced because I'm not ready for this yet. I've discussed with my parents and every time instead of understanding me they start telling me that you're a kafirah you'll go to hell on this. You'll take us into hell. That's wrong. My family is Islamic extremist, they force teachings on everyone. Will I go to hell? What's it like to live in a house where you've to follow Islam by force and beating. I feel suffocated while living with them. What does Islam say about parents who force their children.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I be forced by my parents?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49746/can-i-be-forced-by-my-parents)

Comment: Also see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/80292/ and regarding obedience in niqab.

Answer (score 0):

sorry to hear that, many madhab believe that it is not compulsory to wear "**niqab"** it is base on your preference it is (mustahab) and you know islam is not a religion that force. As long as you dress modest you should be fine but as you said, you do it to "avoid conflict" allah said in surah is "۞ وَقَضَىٰ رَبُّكَ أَلَّا تَعْبُدُوٓا۟ إِلَّآ إِيَّاهُ وَبِٱلْوَٰلِدَيْنِ إِحْسَـٰنًا ۚ إِمَّا يَبْلُغَنَّ عِندَكَ ٱلْكِبَرَ أَحَدُهُمَآ أَوْ كِلَاهُمَا فَلَا تَقُل لَّهُمَآ أُفٍّۢ وَلَا تَنْهَرْهُمَا وَقُل لَّهُمَا قَوْلًۭا كَرِيمًۭا ٢٣" For your Lord has decreed that you worship none but Him. And honour your parents. If one or both of them reach old age in your care, never say to them ˹even˺ ‘ugh,’ nor yell at them. Rather, address them respectfully" you are not Kafira and inshallah you will not go to hell, the first hijab Allah put was in this ayat "tell the believing men and women to lower their gaze and gurad their modesty" if people were doing that then we would not have this problem. Islam teaches that every individual has the right to choose their own path in life, and that no one should be forced to do something that goes against their conscience. The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said, “There is no compulsion in religion” keep doing du'a for them and teaching them, may allah have mercy on us.

Comment: "many madhab believe that it is not compulsory to wear "niqab" it is base on your preference it is (mustahab) and you know islam is not a religion that force" this statement is self-contradictory I assume that you meant to say that it is **not compulsory**, but the first part of your sentence says otherwise.

Answer (score -4):

You can wear a niqab if there is chance of you being kidnapped by some groups who believe it is lawful to kidnap girls and rape them. This way you can conceal your beauty and idea of kidnapping won't come to them. Actually this niqab practice came to existence from this fear and you can see non Muslim groups in countries like India covering their face. If there is no chance of kidnapping like in modern societies, it is better not to cover the face as it is your identity that Allah has given you.  Imagine if Allah has made all our faces same, how we will be able to identify mutually. So if everyone wear niqab, how can people identify each other. So if you are in medical field, you should not wear niqab as your identity is important in the field. Prophet (s.a) forbade covering the face even during circumambulating the ka'ba when people of both sex come very close to each other. If people can uncover face in the most sacred place, there is no problem in uncovering face elsewhere if no harm is feared.

About parents who force you, you can follow then in good matters only (معروف) and there is no duty on you to obey them in matters that are against religion. You can argue with them in good way and convince them that it is not required in Islam.